# How to Override a method based on a condition

Tags: java, overriding

In my BOOKING class I have this method to calculate the total amount

```
public void calcTotal(){
    total = amount*priceperbooking;

}
```

I created a subclass called BOOKING_APPLICATION and I want to override the calcTotal() method if amount > 5 then it must subtract 15% of the total

Here is what I tried but it does not work:

```
public void calcTotal(){
 if (super.amount>5) {
     super.total = super.total-(15/100.0*super.total);
 }

}
```

When I run it its giving me the original total, not taking out 15%
What am I doing wrong

Edit: Here is the code of my main class

```
public class Diving_Adventures{
static BOOKING obj1 = new BOOKING();
static BOOKING_APPLICATION obj2 = new BOOKING_APPLICATION();


public static void main(String[] args) {

    obj1.setName();
    obj1.setNumber();
    obj1.setAmount();
    obj1.setPriceperbooking();
    obj1.calcTotal();
    obj2.calcTotal();



    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, obj1.toString());
}


}
```

I'm assuming by obj1.calcTotal() it will calculate the total and  by obj2.calcTotal it will take out the 15% but it does not work

Here is the full code of my BOOKING class:

```
private String name;
private int number;
public int amount;
public double priceperbooking;
public double total;





public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public double getPriceperbooking() {
    return priceperbooking;
}

public void setName() {

    this.name =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name");;
}

public void setNumber() {

    this.number = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number"));
}

public void setAmount() {

    this.amount =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount"));
}

public void setPriceperbooking() {

    this.priceperbooking = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price per bookin"));;
}


public void calcTotal(){
    total = amount*priceperbooking;

}





@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customer name: "+name+"\n"+"number"+ number + "\namount=" + amount + 
            "\n priceperbooking=" + priceperbooking + "\n total=" + total ;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the complete code?

Comment: Or preferably limit it to [mcve] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: Anyway for not it looks like you are assigning to `super.total` its current value reduced by 15%. I am guessing that current `super.total` value is `0` so its 15% is also 0, which leads us to `0 - 15%*0` which is still 0.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to write `85/100.0*super.amount*super.priceperbooking;`? I am also wondering why are you using `super.xxx` here. If you are able to access those fields it means that they ware not private (which doesn't look right) so you should be able to skip `super.` here. `super.` should be used if you have another field with same name and you want to specify that you want to use field from superclass and not the variable declared in current class.

Comment: Where is `total` declared? If it's in `BOOKING` then each instance (`obj1`, `obj2`) has a different `total`....

Comment: Yes total is declared in the BOOKING class

Comment: `obj1` and `obj2` are *separate* instances which means their fields are unrelated. Calling `obj1.calcTotal();` will set fields of `obj1` but fields of `obj2` are still in their default state. You can create another instance `BOOKING_APPLICATION` like `static BOOKING_APPLICATION obj3 = new BOOKING_APPLICATION();` and it also will be separated from the others (meaning setting `obj1` will not affect aither `obj2` nor `obj3`).

Comment: In that case, you only need to create `BOOKING_APPLICATION` and it will take care of the logic (ie `amount > 5`).

Comment: @Pshemo I understand now but how can I fix this I’m really stuck I’m new to this

Comment: Solution depends on what you want to achieve, but I am guessing all you need to do is create one instance of `BOOKING_APPLICATION` (you probably don't want separate BOOKING instance), set up its properties like you did for `obj1` (so do it for `obj2` this time) and then call `obj2.calcTotal();`. You just need to ensure that inside that method you will let it calculate starting value same way BOOKING did (see answer posted by @breezee) and then you can reduce it by amount you wanted (you may also need to use `setTotal(calculatedValue)` since `total` is probably private (or at least should be).

Comment: What I’m trying to achieve is when I input an amount and if it’s greater than 5 then I need to override the calcTotal() by subtracting the discount amount from the total price due

Comment: @user8705857 That is what I assumed. So all you need is single `BOOKING_APPLICATION` instance, set it up with some data, and then call its `calcTotal()` method which can look like one provided by breezee.

Answer (score 2):

In your derived class:

```
public void calcTotal() {
    total = super.calcTotal();
    if (amount > 5) {
       total = total - (15/100.0 * total); 
    }
}
```

You are mising on calculating the `total` first, as mentioned.

Comment: Let me just add my main class in there I think the total is calculated there

Comment: @user8705857 Don't describe your code, show it. Otherwise we can just guess what is the real problem, but guessing is not very efficient way of solving problems.